# Choosing one number out of two numbers. R

Tags: r, random, numbers

I am trying to create a for loop where p would choose either of two number.

E.g:

```
for (p in 0:runif (1, 0, 1))
{
   if (p == 0.8)
   {
       all.wells[[i]]$state.names == "C" 
   } 
   if (p == 0.2) 
   {
       all.wells[[i]]$state.names == "A"
   }
}
```

The only two possible values for evaluation are 0.2 and 0.8.

I am pretty sure the above loop is long and time consuming.

Comment: The loop definitely isn't long and time consuming.  It's almost definitely not what you intended though...

Comment: Is @Matthew's answer what you wanted, i.e. sample `C` and `A` with probabilities `0.8` and `0.2`? Otherwise, you need to be more clear in your question.

Comment: Sorry I meant not long but wrong and time consuming because it is just a little loop within big loop. So it was going through the big loop for a long time until it hit either 0.8 or 0.2

anywyas thanks for the answer. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 6):

Do you mean that you want "C" with probability .8, and "A" with probability .2?  If so:

```
N <- 100 # nrow all.wells?
sample(c("C", "A"), N, prob=c(.8, .2), replace=TRUE)
```

Comment: I was looking for something that would pull out either .8 or .2 from the list.

Comment: I could not figure it out so this what I came up with: 
 for (p in runif (1, 0,1))
             {if (p <=0.2){
               p = 0.2}
              else { p = 0.8}

But now it is giving me error saying that there is unexpected "=" sign in else statement.